Googleフォームからのメール送信がうまくいかない
以下のスクリプトをGoogleフォームに入力しているのですが、メール送信ができません。
エラーの原因は何でしょうか。
エラー通知:
Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,String,String) don't match the method signature for GmailApp.sendEmail.

スクリプト:
// FormApp.getActiveForm()
function sendform(e){
    var items = e.response.getItemResponses();
    var msg = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        var q = item.getItem().getTitle();
        var a = item.getResponse();
        msg += q + ':' + a + '\n\n';
    }
    GmailApp.sendEmail('メールアドレス', '件名', msg);
}


The parameters (String,String,String,String,String) don't match the method signature for GmailApp.sendEmail.は、GmailApp.sendEmail('a','b','c','d','e')のようにsendEmailメソッドへ文字列を5つの引数として使用した場合に発生すると思われます。表示されているスクリプトを見ますと、GmailApp.sendEmail('メールアドレス', '件名', msg)で使用されている引数は3つの文字列です。この場合は上記のようなエラーは発生しません。このことから、表示されているスクリプトと実際のエラーが発生するスクリプトとは異なるのではないかと思われますがいかがでしょうか。

ご回答ありがとうございます！ご見解通りです。説明不足で申し訳ございませんが、メールアドレスを複数（'メール１','メール２'...)と設定していました。メールアドレス1件の場合と、2件の場合では、プログラムの動作に影響があるのでしょうか？

ご返事ありがとうございます。メールアドレスを複数（'メール１','メール２'...)と設定していました。メールアドレス1件の場合と、2件の場合では、プログラムの動作に影響があるのでしょうか？について、残念ながら何がしたいのか理解できませんでした。申し訳ありません。同じメールを複数のメールアドレスへ独立して送る場合はループを使ってGmailApp.sendEmailを実行する必要があると思います。ccとして送る場合は、4番目の引数へオブジェクトとして{cc: "mail1,mail2,,,"}を使用すると可能です。Ref

CCの件、ご教授くださりありがとうございます！全くの初心者なもので、説明等わかりづらく申し訳ございませんでした。ご回答、ありがとうございました！

sendMail メソッドで複数のアドレスを指定する書き方はカンマ区切りです。
例:
GmailApp.sendEmail('xxx@gmail.com,yyy@gmail.com,zzz@gmail.com', '件名', msg);


ご教授くださりありがとうございます！シングルクオーテーションの使い方が間違っていたようです。ありがとうございました！
